# How to create and manage custom themes for whole Android system?

Tags: android

I know how to create and apply styles and themes thanks to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html. However, this method only works for our own activity or application.

I'd like to create themes that could dress the whole system (i.e. all activities). Of course, I'd like to select one of these theme by programing. If I could customize the status bar as well, it would be perfect.

I didn't find out documentation about that. Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done programatically; the only ways I've seen it done is by manually replacing all of the graphics files that the OS uses. You can see those files, as your emulator would use at least, in (your sdk folder)\platforms(your platform version)\data\res. As for how to copy them onto your phone, that's a whole different matter and isn't really related to the subject of Stack Overflow. I suggest instead you go to the [XDA Developpers, Hero Themes](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=514) forum. You can download all kinds of themes there, and you might be able to find a tutorial there on how to make your own.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer Steve.

It's a shame this can't be done programatically. Maybe in a future version, I'm hoping...