# Creating a custom android UI

Tags: android, user-interface

does anyone know how I would get started creating a custom android UI?
it wouldn't be an app. Once you install it, it would change the appearance of your UI until you uninstall it.

I've done some research but it doesn't seem to be possible/available yet??

If anyone could help or link me to a site on how to to get started that'd be awesome, thx!

I program using eclipse, btw.

This is basically what i want to do, but i want to design it myself http://www.intomobile.com/2011/02/09/sentio-ui-android-home-replacement-app/
How would I get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand your question about what you really want. So i am trying to provide every possible solution.

If you are talking about Home Replacements.

Here is an example by Google :-

[Android Home Replacement Sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html)

and if you are not talking about Home Replacement and you found android layout designing a bit hard then you can use DroidDraw. Just Google DroidDraw, download it and install it on your PC/MAC. It gives you the features like drag and drop widgets, set their property visually and lots more. You can generate the android layout without writing a single line of xml code using droid draw.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html
that site is soooo close to what I want to do. Basically yes, move around everything on the desktop. Change where and how things are displayed. Create a custom UI. I'm going to look into this more and hopefully find something.. If you have any other ideas to help I'd greatly appreciate it friend : )

Comment: This is something I think would help you get a better understanding of what I want to do http://www.intomobile.com/2011/02/09/sentio-ui-android-home-replacement-app/

Comment: ok for something like that you need to go deep in android...here is android's original home screen's source code :- http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=tree

It will give a good idea. and if you want more just google "Android home replacement source code" or something similar. You will surely find some samples to help you out.

Comment: and if my answer is helpful. PLEASE accept it my my friend. Happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to create a custom theme that can be selected by the user. There unfortunately is VERY little documentation around that. The most extensive writeup I've found is at http://www.android.net/forum/custom-android-themes/58323-tutorial-making-themes.html, and after reviewing it I wasn't really able to get too far myself.

A similar question was also asked at [How to create and manage custom themes for whole Android system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477992/how-to-create-and-manage-custom-themes-for-whole-android-system). Let me know if you find something that works for you.

Comment: http://www.intomobile.com/2011/02/09/sentio-ui-android-home-replacement-app/

This is what I want to do, but in my own way... don't know how to get started

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should read the document about this site,i think i will help you.most of the ui element can create by xml file,or coding. if you want to know more about that,to read this site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Comment: I've read it 3 or 4 times :(. I'm trying to figure out how to create a new UI from the standard one android gives you. All the website shows is the different kinds of XML and View's I can create in an XML.